# Edit map with "R for leaflet"

Tags: html, r, leaflet

I have a script which allows me to generate a map with with "R for leaflet" :

```
library(htmlwidgets)
library(raster)
library(leaflet)

# PATHS TO INPUT / OUTPUT FILES
projectPath = "path"
#imgPath = paste(projectPath,"data/cea.tif", sep = "")
#imgPath = paste(projectPath,"data/o41078a1.tif", sep = "") # bigger than standard max size (15431804 bytes is greater than maximum 4194304 bytes)
imgPath = paste(projectPath,"/test.tif", sep = "")
outPath = paste(projectPath, "/leaflethtmlgen.html", sep="")

# load raster image file
r <- raster(imgPath)

# reproject the image, if necessary
#crs(r) <- sp::CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

# color palette, which is interpolated ?
pal <- colorNumeric(c("#FF0000", "#666666", "#FFFFFF"), values(r),
                    na.color = "transparent")

# create the leaflet widget
m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addRasterImage(r, colors=pal, opacity = 0.9, maxBytes = 123123123) %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, values = values(r), title = "Test")


# save the generated widget to html
# contains the leaflet widget AND the image.
 saveWidget(m, file = outPath, selfcontained = FALSE, libdir = 'leafletwidget_libs')
```

My problem is that this is generating a html file and I need this map to be dyanamic. For example, when a user click on some html button which is not integrate on the map, I want to add a rectangle on the map. Any solutions would be welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaflet itself does not provide the interactive functionality you are looking for. One solution is to use [shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com), which is a web application framework for R. From simple R code, it generates a web page, and runs R on the server-side to respond to user interaction. It is well [documented](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/), has a [gallery](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/) of examples, and a [tutorial](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/) to get new users started.

It works well with [leaflet](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html). One of the [examples](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html) on the shiny web site uses it, and also includes a link to the [source code](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/063-superzip-example).

#### Update

Actually, if simple showing/hiding of elements is enough, leaflet alone will suffice with the use of [`groups`](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html). From the question it's not very clear how dynamic you need it to be.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10862955)

Comment: @Akarienta, I extended my answer a bit. The beef is still behind links, but the question is a bit broad to provide a more concrete answer.

Comment: Yes but can I add my raster map to the map without R ?

Comment: @KingOfBabu, when I said "leaflet alone", I meant "R and leaflet" (as opposed to "R, leaflet, and shiny"). And that link I provided explains how to do just that. If you wanted to, I'm sure you could also do it without R directly with JavaScript. But the way your question is written sounds more like you are looking for an R solution.